# How does Google detect duplicate content?

Tags: seo, google-search, duplicate-content

have a quick question about duplicate content. How does google work this all out? In that on my pages I have a form on each page with the same bit of text explaining it, is this going to count against me? The content on each page is original. Surly most sites might have small bits of repeating text on it, would this count against you?

Comment: So long as your form explanation is not the majority of the content but a small portion of it, and rest of the content is unique for each page, it should be fine. Obviously no one is sure at what percent it would be considered duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google will be able to detect that the text you entered correlates to the form, you won't be penalized for duplicate content.

Google will only hold content against you when the entire (or majority of) page content is duplicated (often including meta tags etc),

So no it won't be held against you! :)

Comment: Even in cases where you have two pages that are nearly the same, Google usually just picks one.  It only becomes a problem if you launch duplicates of lots of pages, especially with keyword changes, or especially on multiple domains.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that duplicate content on the same site results in Google being confused as to which is the correct result to show, but not necessarily a penalty. Whereas duplicate content on a 2 different domains can count negatively against one of them.

So far [this](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/duplicate-content-in-a-post-panda-world) page has offered me the most in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Google will consider first indexed pages to get listed in SERP's. Coming to copy content issue, when it is about litter it don't matter, it will be big issue,when your site having multiple pages with same content and pointing to same domain..